# Using a Workflow to auto-populate a form field upon creation in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I would like to have a field automatically be populated with something I define in a workflow.  Currently I have the workflow running upon record creation, however the field is only populated AFTER the user saves the record for the first time.

How can I use a workflow to populate that field before the user saves the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Workflows function on the *server-side*, but you're asking about populating a *client-side* field *before* the server is contacted. Moreover, workflows are triggered asynchronously, which by definition means the record has to be created in advance.

You'll need to either attach a JavaScript function to the `OnSave` event, or trigger the population of the field in a pre-validation or pre-operation .NET plugin. I suppose you could use a Dialog as well, but that would require user input. See the below links for more detail on the differences between plugins, workflows, and dialogs.

- [Options: Plugin, Workflow or Dialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/06/22/options-plugin-workflow-or-dialog.aspx)
- [Automate Business Processes in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328264.aspx)